# Proving A Propositional Logic Statement Using Only Equivalence Laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to figure out how to prove

$$ \neg (p \vee q) \vee (\neg p \wedge q) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \neg p \tag{*} $$

using purely equivalence laws in propositional logic, the equivalence laws being here: [link](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_220_Discrete_Math/2%3A_Logic/2.5%3A_Logical_Equivalences#:%7E:text=Two%20logical%20statements%20are%20logically,helpful%20when%20dealing%20with%20implications).

What I've done so far is to use de Morgan's law on one of the brackets, then use the distributive law. However, I wasn't able to get $\neg p$ from doing so. Could someone explain how to show $\text{(*)}$ using purely equivalence laws?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you get after using de Morgan and the distributive law? It sounds like a step in the right direction to me.

Comment: That's a pointless, complicated way of proving the statement when there is a direct and intuitive proof.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Whats the intuitive proof

Comment: @GilbertS.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

$$\neg(p \lor q) \lor (\neg p \land q)$$

$$ \overset{DeMorgan}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$(\neg p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land q)$$

$$\overset{Distribution}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$\neg p \land (\neg q \lor q)$$

$$\overset{Law of Excluded Middle}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$\neg p \land \top$$

$$\overset{Identity}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$\neg p$$

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove that
$$ ¬(p ∨ q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q) ⇔ ¬p$$

To do this, we'll have to prove two statements:

1. $$\big(¬(p ∨ q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q)\big) \to ¬p$$
2. $$¬p \to \big(¬(p ∨ q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q)\big)$$

The second statement is the converse of the first statement.

Part 1. Prove that
$$¬(p ∨ q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q) \to ¬p$$

If this statement is true, it means that if we assume that ¬(p ∨ q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q) is true, then we can deduce ¬p.

From the identity:
$$ (p \to r) \land (q \to r) = (p \lor q) \to r$$
We get:
$$ (¬(p ∨ q) \to ¬p) \land ((¬p ∧ q) \to ¬p) $$
We need to prove that $¬(p ∨ q) \to ¬p$ and that $(¬p ∧ q) \to ¬p $.

From the fact that ($p \land q) \to p$.
$$¬(p \lor q) = (¬p \land ¬q) \to ¬p$$.

Similarly
$$(¬p \land q) \to ¬p$$.

And we are done. We prove the converse statement by following our steps bottom to top.